# NLog Mail Configuration useSystemNetMailSettings "Parameter useSystemNetMailSettings not supported on MailTarget"

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, nlog

I'm trying to setup NLog to send mail and use my system settings (with a pickup directory) as [documented here](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target)

Here's my NLog configuration

```
<nlog internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="C:\NLogInternal.log" throwExceptions="true" autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<targets>
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\backupservice.log.txt" layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${message}"/>
  <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
  <target xsi:type="EventLog"
             name="event"
             layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${message}"
             source="BackupService"
             eventId="898"
             log="BackupService"
                 />
  <target xsi:type="Mail"
          name="email"
          useSystemNetMailSettings="True" 
          layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${message}" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="email" />
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="event" />
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

Here is my mail setting:

```
  <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="backup@[COMPANY].com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\testmail\Pickup" />
    <network host="mail.[COMPANY].com" password="[PASSWORD]" userName="[EMAIL_ADDRESS]" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Here is the output from NLog's internal logging:

```
** SNIP **
2013-06-20 17:41:03.8368 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.name' to 'email'
2013-06-20 17:41:03.8368 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.useSystemNetMailSettings' to 'True'
2013-06-20 17:41:03.8688 Error Error System.NotSupportedException: Parameter useSystemNetMailSettings not supported on MailTarget
at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object o, String name, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, NLogXmlElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetElement(Target target, NLogXmlElement targetElement)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetsElement(NLogXmlElement targetsElement)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(NLogXmlElement nlogElement, String baseDirectory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content, String baseDirectory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)...
2013-06-20 17:41:03.8688 Error ConfigSectionHandler error:        NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception occurred when loading configuration from C:\Projects\Fee\WindowsServices\BackupService\BackupService\bin\Debug\BackupService.vshost.exe.Config ---> System.NotSupportedException: Parameter useSystemNetMailSettings not supported on MailTarget
at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object o, String name, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, NLogXmlElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetElement(Target target, NLogXmlElement targetElement)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetsElement(NLogXmlElement targetsElement)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(NLogXmlElement nlogElement, String baseDirectory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content, String baseDirectory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(XmlElement element, String fileName)
at NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler.System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if it's a bug in Nlog.

NB: I've tried both useSystemNetMailSettings and UseSystemNetMailSettings.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't get NLog to work **specifically** through NLog but I used a work around. NLog has a ["MethodCall" target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target) that I used like so:

```
      <target name="sendmail" xsi:type="MethodCall" className="BackupLib.Email, BackupLib" methodName="Send">
    <parameter layout="backupservice@[COMPANY].com" />
    <parameter layout="backups@[COMPANY].com" />
    <parameter layout="FATAL ERROR: Backup Service on ${machinename}" />
    <parameter layout="${longdate} - ${callsite} - ${message}" />
  </target>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Fatal" writeTo="sendmail" />
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="event" />
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

This allowed me to call a static method (BackupLib.Email.Send()) that sent out an email for me. Simple yet effective **and** since I used the SMTPClient baked into .NET it used my system email settings!

Glad I finally got this.

Comment: But how did you get the log file? Did you send it attached file?

Comment: What this does is call a method:  

BackupLib.Email.SendMail(From, To, Subject, Body).  

From / To / Subject / Body correspond to the <parameter>s in the <target>.  

An email is generated every time a Fatal error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the extension NLog.MailKit installed and you try to use the `useSystemNetMailSettings` parameter within your target, this will causes the error `Parameter useSystemNetMailSettings not supported on MailTarget`.

Uninstalling the NLog.MailKit package fixed this for me!

The Nlog.MailKit package is only required if you are using NetStandard1.X.